# Deploy Java Web Project on Tomcat without WAR or EAR

Tags: java, tomcat, web, web-deployment

I have a Java Web project (Struts + Spring) working perfectly in my localhost. I have to deploy it on my website, but the Tomcat Manager interface given by the webhost says it cannot upload a WAR file due to safety reasons. When contacting the tech support I was told it is not possible to upload a WAR and that I should try deploying my project by uploading the files directly (I have FTP access).

My problem is that no one at the tech support gave specific instructions on where I should put my project files (I don't know if it should be on de same folder the WAR would be sent to) neither how to start/stop it (Will the Tomcat Manager recognize it once I upload the files?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always try to upload a war file to webapps folder of tomcat.

if tomcat is running with autoDeploy set to true it will auto deploy your application.

i think that the same will happen if you upload the exploded war to the webapps, the context will be the name of the directory you put your files in.

Answer (score 3):

Just place your apllication's **root** folder to the Tomcat's directory **webapps** and configure tomcat to auto deploy. Restart the server and your application will be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

You transfer the files to the same place as the war file would go - but just as an expanded war.

Whether or not tomcat will recognise that the files have changed depends on the configuration of the tomcat server. I'd just give it a go - transfer the files and see what happens. If it doesn't pick up the changes then you'll need to find out from tech support how to restart tomcat.