# how to deploy java web application. steps to deploy

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have done jsp servlet project in eclipse.

I want to upload that project online.

Project Developed in jsp,servlet.
Server : Tomcat 7.0

What are the steps to deploy that project?
What are the needs to our server.
Is that possible to upload our project without war file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097115/deploy-java-web-project-on-tomcat-without-war-or-ear see this will help u

Comment: That's too broad, try to google it - you'll find many posts like [this one](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicm/v8r0m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ig_icm.8.0.2.doc%2Fc_apache-tomcat-deployment.html)

Comment: It may help you [Writing and Deploying a Simple Web Application to GlassFish](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2014/03/writing-and-deploying-simple-web.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What are the steps to deploy that project?"

```
 - Get an online Server depends on your need(Rental/Free). I would   
   suggest you to prefer get server space from cloud like Amazon,Azure  
   and etc. 
 - Once you got the server approval you can access your online   
   server. Then you have to upload you Apache Tomcat server to that   
   server and deploy your .War file.
 - Launch the Apache Tomcat server. Now your service is up
   and running. Then if you wish you  can map your server name in
   global domain server for your online  application.
```

"Is that possible to upload our project without .war file?."

```
.war is standard format for packing application for Java Web Applications. I would suggest you to use consider using either .war or .ear based on type application you have created.
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a Dynamic web project in eclipse, compile and deploy the war in tomcat webapp folder

> $CATALINA_HOME/webapps

If dont want to have a war make use of the tomcat's default ROOT.

> $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT

[Check this](http://mcqueeney.com/blog/replacing-tomcats-root-index-jsp-page/)